# ISNull() Can't retrive the null values in the replace value when it column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use in Sql Server 2012 isNull(@parameter,ColumnName) in a stored Proc

When I send the parameter With null value it return th column without null value

and i need to retrive the null value with the column

Comment: Post the stored procedure? Don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: As long as you don't show us what you have tried so far, it's hard to tell for us why it is not working. Please show relevants parts of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ISNULL()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx):

> Replaces NULL with the specified replacement value.

So if your @parameter is null you get the replacement as a return value which is ColumnName.

The [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) states the following:

> **ISNULL (check_expression , replacement_value)**
>
> Returns the same type as check_expression. If a literal NULL is
> provided as check_expression, returns the datatype of the
> replacement_value. If a literal NULL is provided as check_expression
> and no replacement_value is provided, returns an int.

Comment: so what can i do to make the "ColumnName" return the all values with null

Comment: to get all values including null you just need to use the column value without any ISNULL function, but i guess you need to provide some default value when the column value is null, in this case you need something like ISNULL(Columnname, DefaultValueToUseInCaseOfNULL)